# TextVectorization layer in a deep neaural network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp

I'm training a neural network with Tensorflow for a NLP problem and I'm using the TextVectorization layer as fisrt layer. This layer has one parameter that give me problems : standardize. For this there are some default options but there is also the possibility to create a custum callable. I've got a functions written by me that I want to use in this layer. My functions receive a string in input and give a string in output. This is not compatible with the input and the output for the callable in this layer.
What is the right output and input that this callable has to have?

If there is a way, how can convert my function?

This is my function:

```
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.util import *
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
import re
nltk.download('wordnet')

def my_preprocessing(text)
 text=re.split("\\s+",text)
 wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
 stemmed_words = [wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in text]
 testo = [w for w in stemmed_words if not w.isnumeric()]
 return ' '.join(testo)
```

Comment: Hi @Luca, welcome to SO. Please elaborate your question with the code and some samples of your input data, along with error traces of where your code is failing. Please read [ask] for more details.

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/guide/word_embeddings#text_preprocessing) for the custom standardization with `TextVectorization` which might be helpful to you.